# How can I use a repeat in AMP carousel

Tags: carousel, amp-html, amp-list, amp-mustache

I have an `AMP-LIST` which includes a few `items`, each `item` has some properties. One of these properties is an array of Images that is supposed to be used inside an `AMP-CAROUSEL`. Something like this scheme:

```
    <amp-list src="A/JSON/URL">
        <h2>{{somthing}}</h2>
        <p>{{somthing}}</p>
        <amp-carousel>
             ** AN ARRAY IS NEEDED TO BE RENDERED INSIDE HERE**
        </amp-carousel>
    </amp-list>
```

How can I render the IMAGES array which is part of ITEMS array inside the carousel for every item

```
{
  items: [
    {
       prop:value1,
       images:['image1URL','image2URL','image3URL',....],
    },

    {
       prop:value2,
       images:['image4URL','image5URL',....],
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is your question?! Since your problem description is so vague, I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally some errors and a better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Please edit your post accordingly

Comment: Re-edited, please look at it now

Comment: programming languages? I would edit the tags as well. Adding a similar programming language is allowed

Answer (score 0):

*** Problem Solved : 
It's an AMP-HTML project by the way.
And I managed to get the results by changing the html code to this:

```
    <amp-list src="A/JSON/URL">
        <h2>{{somthing}}</h2>
        <p>{{somthing}}</p>
        <amp-carousel>
             {{#TheImageArray}}
                 <img src={{theURL}} />
             {{/TheImageArray}}
        </amp-carousel>
    </amp-list>
```